# Angular - define modules in multiple files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

I have the following in app.js

```
config = angular.module('config', [])
.constant('Constants', {
        Car: 'BMW', 
        Phone: 'G4'
});

services = angular.module('services', ['config']);
controllers = angular.module('controllers', ['config', 'services']);
app = angular.module('myApp', ['config', 'controllers']);
```

I want to move the "config" module definition to a separate file as I'm expecting it to grow bigger.

Is it possible to move the below portion to a separate file:

```
config = angular.module('config', [])
.constant('Constants', {
        Car: 'BMW', 
        Phone: 'G4'
});
```

Comment: You can't change constant values....

Comment: Can have numerous files..not clear what the exact problem is or what you are asking. Should however be grouping modules as features not components

Comment: I've edited the question for clarity.

Comment: `Is it possible` ... shouldn't you just try it first? If you did what problems arose?

Comment: @charlietfl because we cannot "include" other files in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with doing that.

You just need to make sure the config module will be loaded before the app module

Answer (score 0):

You've chosen very bad structure for your angular app. Please check this url https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-best-practices-directory-structure

And about your question. Instead of using caching variables just do next thing:

```
file0: angular.module('config',[]);
file1: angular.module('config').constant('Constants', {Car: 'BMW', Phone: 'G4'});
file2: angular.module('config').constant('Constants2', {Car: 'BMW', Phone: 'G4'});
```

Comment: I've not mentioned anything about my directory structure. It exactly matches the best practices.

Comment: We can see your structure from the way everything has been declared, vlad is tottaly correct imo. the link he provided is very good aswell.